# Custom Validate single item in a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an simple class that I get from a webservice.

```
public class person 
{
   public string name  { get; set; }
   public int number  { get; set; }
}
```

And a second class in my code

```
public class people
{
   [ValidatePerson]
   public List<person> myPeople;
}
```

and a custom ValidationAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ValidatePerson : ValidationAttribute
{
   protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
   {
     ValidationResult returnValue = ValidationResult.Success;
     return returnValue; // do stuff later
   }
}
```

Because person comes from a webservice I can't add a decorator to it (that I know of) and adding the decorator to the attribute in people means that "value" is a `List<person>` not a person.

The reason I want to validated person not `List<person>` is because I'm using  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model);` in the editortemplate for person and I'd like to have multiple messages like "this is not a valid person" not a block at the top that says "you have 3 invalid people".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new model for person you want to validate, i.e:

```
public class personValidator 
{
   [ValidatePerson]
   public string name  { get; set; }
   public int number  { get; set; }
}
```

Then copy the result of the webservice to your personValidator class, and use it in the View.

Comment: I ended up creating public class 'ValidPerson :person {public ValidPerson(person){...}}' Not as clean as I like because the web service changes something in Person I'll need to tweak more of my code. Also I need person later so I need to convert back.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to recreate a model for person on your end, add the validation annotation to that, deep copy the values from the service person to your local person in the controller or service request, then have a list of the model definition you created in a view model, then use the helper with the list from the view model holding your locally defined person with data annotation, and it will grab the correct validation.